# Button click not working in Fragment

Tags: java, android

I would like to display activity_main on fragment button click.

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);

   Button smart1 = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.smart1);
    smart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           getActivity().onBackPressed();

        }

    });


    return myView;
}
```

Button is not working. It just stays on the same page and nothing happens.

Edited for Nas

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class Splash extends Fragment {

    View myView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);

        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Button smart1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.smart1);
        smart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();

        }

        });


    }
}
```

Here is the Splash.java, it's weird why buttons aren't working. Thank you in advance.

Comment: and what you want to do?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I would like to get the data of my MainActivity onBackPressed

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41310395/6632568

Comment: What are you trying to actually do? You aren't getting anything. You're calling the method that is called in response to back press, not actually simulating a back action. Are you wanting to finish the activity?

Comment: @cricket_007 I would like to transfer to layout activity_main from my fragment button click.

Comment: Then call `getActivity().setContentView`... Or load a Fragment using that layout. The Fragment or FrameLayout is already a part of activity_main, no?

Comment: @cricket_007 No sir, it's not part of activity main. Should I replace getActivity().backPressed to getActivity().setContentView?

Comment: Not necessarily, that's just one option. Can you show `splash.xml`,please

Comment: @cricket_007 [link](http://pastebin.com/HC2X2met) here you go sir

Comment: can you add onBackPressed of activity and splash.xml code..this code looks fine.

Comment: Assuming u have navigated from main to splash.... call getActivity().finish() ,this would stop ur current activity and take u back to last activity. Or second approach is to Define what you wish to do onBackPressed in the activity first

Comment: @santoshkumar here is my onBackPressed code: [link](http://pastebin.com/sQMfGnWZ)

Comment: Don't use PasteBin, please [edit] your question

Comment: You're doing way too much work in `onBackPressed`. I am very confused what you want or why you are trying to load a completely separate activity view within an existing activity

Comment: Use `this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();` for go back in fragments

Comment: onBackPressed is override method .. do you want to create method with the same name as of onBackPressed() ?

Comment: Yes @santoshkumar but I have some concerns. Is there anyway to test the button click? I think it's not working at all. I even tried adding alert box and still not working

Comment: have you debug it? does it show any log on clicking?

Comment: @Nas no logs shown after click. :/

Comment: @Aaron set onclick listener in onViewCreated method or onActivityCreated method if still not working keep clickable true for the parent layout in your case RelativeLayout

Comment: @Nas Where to find onViewCreated and onActivityCreated? I'm sorry I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Button smart1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.smart1);
    smart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
       getActivity().onBackPressed();

    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you but it still not doing anything on button click.

Comment: then try to keep clickable true for the parent layout in your case RelativeLayout

Comment: keep clickable true for your button smart1 too. still not working??

Comment: Yes sir. android:clickable="true" still not giving me any.

Comment: no am told that keep clickable for both parent layout as well as the button view you are trying to fire an event

Comment: But splash.xml doesn't have a parent layout sir.

Comment: your RelativeLayout is parent layout for the button smart1 so try to add clickable true for both smart1 and RelativeLayout .

Comment: I tried adding it to my RelativeLayout and smart1 still not working

Comment: have you implement onclick listener in your fragment calss if so pls post your full fragment class code.

Comment: seems to be no pblm with your code remove getActivity().onBackPressed(); and show a toast inside and check whether toast showing or not.

Comment: Tried  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Button is working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and nothing showing up. What seems to be the problem? :/

Comment: I tried it using another fragment and toast is working fine on button click. What could be the problem?

Comment: no idea. if possible share your project through GitHub. let me check.